# multiline textbox to string

Tags: c#

I have a multiline textbox that I wish to convert to a string,
I found this

string textBoxValue = textBox1.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine,"TOKEN");

But dont understand TOKEN what is TOKEN? whitespace or /n newline ?
If this is the incorrect answer then Please let me know of the correct way of doing this

Thanks

Comment: There's no reason why you can't just keep the newline in the string.  What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: A client has given me Text, this text is a copy (grab) of a application that he has.the only way I can get the text from his application is to copy paste from his application to myn, the clients database is written in a unknown database and I have no way to access the database other then to manually copy paste the text from his application to myn, My application is a multiline textbox that information is pasted into , this info contains newlines and formating I dont need , hence the multiline to string

Comment: further I need to enter this data into SQLite and rewrite his whole application, The company does not wish to have information from the previos application inputted to the new database, there are hyperlinks etc inbedded in the content , so if there is a way I can make the text box only accept RAW data this would be the best.

Answer (score 1):

In the code snippet you gave, "TOKEN" is any value you wish to insert, such as an HTML `<br />` tag, more `Environment.NewLine`s for formatting, or just some random delimiter that will later allow you to split the text on it.

A **very** simple example:

```
string text = textBox1.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "^"); // a random token
string[] lines = test.Split( '^' );
```

If you are handling input from a textbox available on the web, you also need to take into account XSS (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).  Also, in a real scenario I would split on a more complex token and make sure to handle multiple carriage returns in the input value.

EDIT: now that I see your actual requirements, this code may do what you need:

```
// replace newlines with a single whitespace
string text = textBox1.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ");
```

EDIT #2:

> further I need to enter this data into
>   SQLite and rewrite his whole
>   application, The company does not wish
>   to have information from the previos
>   application inputted to the new
>   database, there are hyperlinks etc
>   inbedded in the content , so if there
>   is a way I can make the text box only
>   accept RAW data this would be the
>   best.

Regular Expressions are the way to go for something like this, unless the data is structured enough to load into an XML or HTML DOM and process. You can build regular expressions in a variety of tools (do a Google search for a free online tester and you will find many).  Once you have determined the expressions you need, you can use the Regex object in C# to match, replace, etc.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228595(VS.80).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, "TOKEN" is just a meangingless string, unless it is elsewhere in your code? You can replace "TOKEN" with any text you like.

Edit:

Okay, so you say you're removing NewLine's from your client's text. So you would do it like this. Paste their text into a textBox called textBox2, then use the following:

textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty);